# Error found in 1 file?

Tags: lubuntu, iso, burning

I recently downloaded Lubuntu 14.04 64bit standard PC disc image ISO version.

I tried to burn this image using **xfburn** to cd and dvd, but when I check the disc for defects in the Lubuntu boot main screen, it shows:

```
Error found in 1 file.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the downloaded ISO is defective.
In order to check the ISO file, run an md5sum for the ISO in the terminal, for example:

```
md5sum lubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

and verify that the calculated hash matches with the given hash appropriate to your Ubuntu version which can be found [here on the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

Re-download the image if necessary, and try again.

Comment: What happens if the image is found to be valid, but I still have that error?